# Mongoose save() method not updating mongo

Tags: mongoose

my mongoose collection looks something like below:

collection Name: test

```
[
{
 _id: xxx,
 alerts: { 
          level1 : {
                      list: [ {'name': 'John'},{'name':'balm']
                    }
        }
},
{
 _id: yyy,
 alerts: { 
          level1 : {
                      list: [ {'name': 'cindy'},{'name':'terry']
                    }
        }
},

]
```

I am writing a function that will find all 'Johns' in the name field of list and replace it with 'Joan'.

so far I have the following script:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        ,testModel = mongoose.model('test');

    testModel.find(query, function(err,docs){
     docs.forEach(function(doc){
        if(doc.alerts.level1.list.length>0) {
            var nameChagned = false;
            doc.alerts.level1.list.forEach(function(obj){
                 if(obj.name === 'John') { 
                    obj.name = 'Joan'; 
                     namechanged = true;
                 }
             }
            if(nameChanged) { doc.save();}
         }
      }
  }
```

At the end of the script when I check the collection, the values are not updated. 
Any clues what i could be missing here ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In the source code above you are never updating the `nameChanged` variable, so the `doc.save()` command is never run. You are introducing a global variable in the line `namechanged = true` (note that JavaScript variables are case-sensitive). In the declaration you use the variable name `nameChagned` so the `nameChanged` variable always evaluates to a falsy value.

It is also considered good practice to use a callback for the `doc.save()` method:

```
doc.save(function (err, doc, numberAffected) {
  if (err) {
    return handleError(err);
  }
});
```

So you can handle any errors that occur when saving the document. See [Mongoose Docs for Model#save](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save).

You should also check the `query` you are passing to the find function. Maybe you do not find any documents so that the `docs` argument is empty.

Comment: Hi @runtimeZero if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.